# How to test if jmx plugin is working in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am new to the whole ElasticSearch framework and have downloaded an installed the logstash-input-jmx plugin and now I need to test my configuration but I can't find in any of the LogStash documentation exactly how to test the plugin. All they have in the plugin documentation in GitHub is a sentence down at the bottom that says to start LogStash and test your plugin, they don't tell you exactly how to accomplish that. As a matter of fact that seems to be the standard blurb for all of the plugins which isn't very helpful if you're coming in without any knowledge of the framework.

Here are some details for my configuration if that helps:
logstash.conf

```
    input {
        jmx
        {
            path => "file://*machinename*/D$/LS/logstash-5.1.1/config/jmx"
            polling_frequency => 15
            type => "jmx"
        }
    }
    filter {
        it [type] == "jmx" {
            if ("Memory.HeapMemoryUsage" in [metric_path] or "Memory.NonHeapMemoryUsage" in [metric_path]) {
                ruby {
                    code => "event['memoryUsage'] = event['metric_value_number'] * 100"
                    add_tag => [ "memoryUsage" ]
                } 
            }   
         }
    }
```

jmx.conf:

```
    {
    "host" : *ip address of machine*,
    "port" : *jmx listener port*,
    "queries" : [
        "object_name" : "java.lang:type=Memory",
        "object_alias" : "Memory"
    ]
    }
```

TIA,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by doing a complete uninstall/reinstall of the framework and found a very good tutorial on Ivan Krizsan's blog (https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2015/09/27/jmx-monitoring-with-the-elk-stack/) that was instrumental in helping me get the plug-in up and running.